# append (distribute) variables from a matrix into to a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am using function `meshgrid` to create 2 matrixes and function `num2cell` to make a cell array from one matrix.

```
latVectr = 1:1:5;
longVectr = 10:2:20;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(latVectr,longVectr);

CELX = num2cell(X);
```

I would like to distribute the variables of the second matrix to the cells of the created cell array as following:

```
X{1,1}(1,2) = Y(1,1);
X{1,2}(1,2) = Y(1,2);
;
;
;
;X(n,m)(1,1) = Y(n,m)
```

I can do it with a loop. Is there any other *more elegant* way how to do it?

Comment: please check out my [other solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15070206/1714410), I feel it is better than the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
CELX = cellfun(@(x,y) [x,y], num2cell(X), num2cell(Y), 'UniformOutput', false );
```

In fact, I feel this solution is more elegant than my [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065056/1714410)

Comment: yes, it is, just for the coherence, both `X` and `Y` have to be a cell array (using `num2cell`)

Comment: @MasterPJ - indeed you are correct regarding the `num2cell` - I edited the answer accordingly. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you wish `CELX{ k, l }` will be `[ X(k,l) Y(k,l) ]`.
This can be done through

```
CELX = mat2cell( cat(3, X, Y ), ones(size(X,1),1), ones(1, size(X,2)), 2 );
```

**EDIT:**
You may want to correct for the dimensionality of the resulting cells using

```
CELX = cellfun( @squeeze, CELX, 'UniformOutput', false );
```

Comment: the input of this a little bit different ... `CELX{1,1}` is actually `<1x1x2>` so it has a value at `(:,:,1)` and at `(:,:,2)`. But it is pretty much close (and can be adjusted) to what I was looking for and it will definitely do the job: )